How to gracefully close a tinyrpc.RPCServer?
I am using tinyrpc.RPCServer in Python to implement a simple RPCServer but I am unable to find documentation or code on how to gracefully close this server. Anyone had this issue ?
The code here and documentation here are not helpfull.
